# Programmatically set custom RPC URL in MetaMask

Tags: web3js, metamask

How can I set a custom RPC URL into web3 object programmatically instead of doing it on the MetaMask?

My intention is to prevent any mistake from users.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Metamask doesn't support this feature yet. but as far as I know, they are working on it. You can keep an eye on this [issue](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/5101), and also [eip2015](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-2015.md).

Comment: I doubted this will works for MetaMask. What I want to achieve is the set the endpoint in the MetaMask's web3 object rather than users have to do it manually on the MetaMask.